# Form validation using Jquery onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have written a validation code for my form in jQuery. Everything seems to be correct, but it doesn't work. Help me!

HTML FORM:

```
<form role="form" name="form1" id="form1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Contact Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="usr" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Full Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Company Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Company Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="eml">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="eml" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phn">Contact Number</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phn" placeholder="98689-98689">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Remarks</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id="submtbtn" style="height:30px ; width:60px;   padding: 5px 5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-info" onClick="AddNew(); this.form.reset()">Insert</button>
    <button style="height:30px ; width:60px;   padding: 5px 5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-info" onClick="this.form.reset()">Clear</button>
    <button id="cnclbtn" style="height:30px ; width:60px;   padding: 5px 5px;   background-color: #f1f1f1; " type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Here is the validation script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            usr: "required",
            pwd: "required",
            eml: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            phn: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            }
        },
        messages: {
            usr: "Please enter your first name",
            pwd: "Please enter your last name",
            eml: {
                required: "Please provide Email address ",
                email: "Please enter valid Email address"
            },
            phn: {
                required: "Please provide a Phone Number",
                minlength: "Your Phone Number must be 10 digits"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#submtbtn").click(function () {
        $("#form1").valid();
    });
});
```

Please point out the error. Thank you.

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cherry1993/vwo0r0h6/

Comment: Can you expand on "it doesn't work"? It's easier for you to explain the specific problem you have than for, say, 20 people to look at the code (or run the fiddle) and find out themselves. Help us to help you!

Comment: It would help if you understood how to use jsFiddle.  You have not included jQuery or the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [your jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cherry1993/vwo0r0h6/), after removing the `<script>` and `</script>` tags from the JavaScript pane, and including jQuery and the jQuery Validate plugin, it started working... but only for the `usr` field.

https://jsfiddle.net/vwo0r0h6/2/

It does not work on any of the other fields because you forgot to include a `name` attribute on those input elements.  This plugin only uses the `name` attribute, not the `id`, to keep track of the form inputs.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pwd" placeholder="Company Name">
```

**Working DEMO:  https://jsfiddle.net/vwo0r0h6/3/**

---

**Bonus**:

You don't need to worry wether the value within your custom message matches the rule's parameter.  Simply use the parameter's placeholder, `{0}`, within the custom message and its value will get entered dynamically.  See working demo above.

```
minlength: "Your Phone Number must be {0} digits"
```